# How to make links after they are visited not have any styling rules

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using **React** and doing a task where, when selected; the new link gets styled accordingly. The problem is that **when I click on the new link it is supposed to be red** and no styling should be applied to it. However, it turns to a darker blue and is left underlined until I click somewhere else on the page.

Something to note here. If I click somewhere else after I have clicked the link it will turn red without the underline. I want it to happen on the first click however.

These are the styles after a link is clicked:

[image]

This is how it is:

[image]

---

This is how it should be:

[image]

Here is my code:

style:

```
.zone-selected {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

zone:

```
  const title = this.props.isSelected
      ? <a href="#" className="zone-selected">
          {this.props.zone.name}
        </a>
      : <a href="#">
          {this.props.zone.name}
        </a>;
```

You can ignore all the other stuff. This basically is saying if the conditional is true apply the styling if not then no styling.

Comment: use the elements panel to see why it's styled that way. you probably have a rule for `a:visited` or `a:link` etc that come built into browsers. you'll need to override them if you want different styles

Comment: also you can just conditionally apply the classname, not the entire element

Comment: @azium I added the console of the styles after the link has been clicked. It looks like my styling is canceled out.

Comment: right. do you know how to fix it then? you need to write a css rule that has higher specicifity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is best practice or the "right way" but I got it to work so I will post what I have in case someone else comes across this.

I needed to add a new style to the `.zone-selected`. I needed to override the focus property. I also wanted the hover styling gone, but for some reason if I had to do it a little different I will show below.

```
.zone-selected {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

.zone-selected:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

With this you would think I could so something like:

```
 .zone-selected:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: green;
}
```

For some reason this would not work so I had to just go into the a tag itself and apply it like so:

```
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style definition to your CSS:

```
.zone-selected:visited {}
```

Comment: An empty style definition is not going to do anything. It doesn't override any styles for elements of that class.